# Python OLA TypeError: can only assign array

Tags: python, arrays, lighting

from ola.ClientWrapper import ClientWrapper

I get this error while assigning to an array a  multiprocessing.Manager.list slice or

```
pippo =[0]*10
self.dmx_data[0:10]= pippo[0:10]
```

this is the error:

```
TypeError: can only assign array (not "list") to array slice
```

is this library related?

this is the declaration:

```
class Ola(multiprocessing.Process):                          
    def __init__(self ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~# ola
        self.wrapper = None
        self.universe = 0
        self.TICK_INTERVAL = 10  # in ms                               
        self.channels = 512
        #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #     
        self.dmx_data = array.array('B',(0,)*(self.channels))
```

Comment: can you show declaration of self.dmx_data?

Answer (score 1):

Your variable pippo is of type list, not array. Try using zeros(10) to generate an array of ten zeros.

Comment: I understand that are different types, but why if I do   self.dmx_data[0]= int(pippo[0]), one to one, this works?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the fact that a slice of a list is still a list, and you can't assign arrayslice to be a list, while when you only do it for one number, it can be interpreted as an int instead of a list, which is allowed.